# Setting up SVN server on Windows 7

Tags: windows, svn, git, mercurial, java

## Short

My OS is: Windows 7 Ultimate and IDE is Netbeans. Want to work with 2-3 devs on PHP projects. After research I found that it's possible with GIT. Found [this](http://gitstack.com/) solution. But it's installing apache server. (I don't need any web server: I already have one - IIS7)

## Question

Is there any free solution (I mean not only GIT, maybe something else) that will work with Netbeans and allows to work with group of developers?

## Detailed

I told with some devs. They suggested to use Github or BitBucket instead of running own git server. **But**

- first off, Github doesn't allow private projects for free, bitbucket allows but limited users.
- second off, what if my project is confidential, and I don't want to
  upload it to any public project server?

  I want to find some solution that will work ONLY for small dev group. So want to serve my own repo.

Some of hirep guys suggested, to install tortoisesvn. But how to give access to other users over internet to repo created by Tortoise?

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You should change your title. This is not a SVN question, it is a general version control question.

Comment: Bite the bullet, let it install Apache.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to decide between using a 'centralized' version control system, or a 'distributed' one.

The centralized options, such as CVS, SVN, P4, require you to run a server. It sounds like that is not what you want.

That leaves you with the distributed options, such as Mercurial, Git, Bazaar, Fossil, etc.

You **do not** need to sign up for Bitbucket or Github to use these, though those services can be convenient.

For instance, in Mercurial, you can:

- Share your repo as a plain directory, such as with:

  - a flash drive
  - a network share
  - FTP or anything else

Or:

- Share your repo over the local network using the builtin 'hg serve' HTTP server

  - This is often the simplest for a relatively small group of people

Git has similar features, as do other DVCS tools.

The fundamental thing to understand about DVCS is that everyone has a copy of the entire history of the project, so there is no 'server' to connect to where data stored. Or alternatively, anyone can act as a 'server'.

It is important, however, to build an understanding amongst your developers about which direction changes will flow from person to person, to avoid confusion.

Here is a NetBeans tutorial on using Mercurial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to find the Apache route (vs IIS) is better supported or at least documented. There's at least one product out there that will simplify the installation for you: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Another option would be to setup a Virtual Machine of virtually any distribution of Linux and just run a native SVN server.

Either way, you're going to need more than TortoiseSVN as it's only a client. You'll need to install an SVN server package and open up a few ports to the Internet before other users will be able to connect to repo hosted by you.